# How to run ajax in wamp server

Tags: jquery, ajax, wamp

I am working on ajax for days now and it still won't work. So I decided to download a sample program using ajax but it still won't work. Is there something wrong with my server? This doens't return any error. But it does not show my jquery.

client.php

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1) Create some html content that can be accessed by jquery
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
  <h2> Client example </h2>
  <h3>Output: </h3>
  <div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text will be replaced</div>

  <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  $(function () 
  {

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var id = data[0];              //get id
        var vname = data[1];           //get name
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // 3) Update html content
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname);     //Set output element html
        //recommend reading up on jquery selectors they are awesome http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
      } 
    });

  }); 
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

api.php

```html
<?php 

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "root";

  $databaseName = "ajax01";
  $tableName = "variables";

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 1) Connect to mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");            //query
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result    

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think your query should be `("SELECT * FROM '".$tableName."'");` Let me know if it works or not and I'll have a second glance. ;)

Comment: `"SELECT * from $tableName"` should work in PHP no issues

Comment: Hi @Filthy_Rich it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok. Is it doing absolutely nothing when you run it?

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network. That's the best place to start debugging. Also are any errors thrown in console?

Comment: it display "this element will be accessed by jquery and this text will be replaced" no errors at all. @Filthy_Rich

Comment: no errors thrown. i think it did not run the ajax part at all @charlietfl

Comment: To be honest, I think it's potentially because you have to define whether your either using `type: POST,` or `type: GET` with AJAX. I've always used either of these two, so my knowledge is either lacking on the subject, or you have to either post (POST) the data to your AJAX script somehow. I don't believe GET would be viable for you.

Comment: but there are no data to be passed. so i skipped that part.

Comment: GET is fine and it is set by default if no other type is set. There is a lot of detail in the network tab ...what is status? Can see what is returned also

Answer (score 0):

I guess your link is fine but put a `console.log(data)` and check what is coming from that using your browser developer tools.

Oh and in PHP use a header in the first line 
`header('Content-type: application/json');`

Comment: hi. where shall i place the console.log(data);? im kinda new with ajax

Answer (score 0):

If you have empty return body then maybe you have error in PHP code which is silenced by php.ini

Try inserting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

at the top of your PHP file and see what happens in your browser's Network panel (open developer tools - F12)